# Environment variables in vite react application are being printed as plain text in network calls tab

Tags: reactjs, vite

I was going through the network calls for my react app, and I noticed that when getting one of my utility files, all the environment variables I defined in .env, following vite's guidelines are being shown as plain text.

How do I stop this? What am I doing wrong?
[image: networks call tab]

Why are the environment variables being printed as plain text?

Comment: are you setting environment variables directly in .env file or setting them in github panel?

Secondly please share image of client side code (the current file) or the server side code where you're setting the environment variable (obviously with arbitrary value hidden). will help see what your problem is

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.